# ListView with custom data

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, compiler-errors

I'm new to ASP and I would like send my own data to `ListView` (I usually use Model only). So I need something as below:

```
public class ProduktDetailClass
    {
        public Model.Produkt Produkt { get; set; }
        public int DopravaZdarmaOd { get; set; }
    }

public List<ProduktDetailClass> DetailProduktuListView_GetData([RouteData]string URLProdukt)
{
    var context = new Model.Entities();

    var mujProdukt = new Model.Produkt();
    mujProdukt = context.Produkt.Where(c => c.URL == URLProdukt).FirstOrDefault();

    List<ProduktDetailClass> produktDetail = new List<ProduktDetailClass>();
    produktDetail.Add(new
    {
        Produkt = mujProdukt,
        DopravaZdarmaOd = 600
    });

    return produktDetail;
}
```

And template:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="DetailProduktuListView" runat="server"
            ItemType="List<ProduktDetailClass>"
            SelectMethod="DetailProduktuListView_GetData">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <h1 class="h1DetailProduktu"><%#Item.Nazev %></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

I think that is a novice mistake. Maybe I have bad syntax for the arguments at `produktDetail.Add()`.

**Compiler errors:**

> error CS1502: Některé argumenty přetěžované metody, která je nejlepší
>   shodou pro deklaraci
>   System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(TemplateProdukt.ProduktDetailClass),
>   jsou neplatné.
>
> error CS1503: Argument 1: Nelze převést z typu AnonymousType#1 na
>   typ TemplateProdukt.ProduktDetailClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an `anonymous` type, but you need to add `ProduktDetailClass` to your list like this :-

```
List<ProduktDetailClass> produktDetail = new List<ProduktDetailClass>();
produktDetail.Add(new ProduktDetailClass
    {
        Produkt = mujProdukt,
        DopravaZdarmaOd = 600
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for solutions (this and below). Both seems to work. Now I have problem with ItemType="List<ProduktDetailClass>" in template - should I create a namespace? OR is there simplier way?

Comment: @ŠárkaJanková - Problem with item type as in? What is the error?

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: Typ List<ProduktDetailClass> nelze načíst. In English something as Type List<ProduktDetailClass> can not be loaded

Answer (score 0):

`List<ProduktDetailClass> produktDetail = new List<ProduktDetailClass>()` measn list of `ProduktDetailClass` object.
so, you can't add anymouse type to `produktDetail`

try this..

```
List<ProduktDetailClass> produktDetail = new List<ProduktDetailClass>();
ProduktDetailClass obj=new ProduktDetailClass ();
obj.Produkt =mujProdukt;
obj.DopravaZdarmaOd =600;
produktDetail.Add(obj);
```